# Determine Oracle session client character set?

Tags: oracle, character-set

I *know* how the database characterset (`NLS_CHARACTERSET` in `select * from v$nls_parameters;`) and the client character set (the client environment setting `NLS_LANG`) interact.

What I can't find out however, is how or if I can determine, *for an established session*, what Oracle thinks the current client characterset is.

*Is this possible at all?*

Note: `SELECT * FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS;` does *not* include the character set (on 10g2).

To make absolutely clear what I'd like to accomplish:

1. NLS_LANG is set in client environment to an arbitrary value (for example `GERMAN_GERMANY.WE8MSWIN1252`)
2. Database application[*] starts and establishes a connection/session to the Oracle database.
3. Database application[*] wants to "ask" *Oracle* (not its OS environment) what the client character set is Oracle will assume.

[*]: If the db application is sqlplus, the example would look as follows:

```
...
sqlplus /nolog
connect user/pass@example
*magic command*;
   CLIENT CHARACTERSET = ...
```

---

Jack's note in his answer raises two important points:

- With Oracle, *who* does the characterset translation. Is it the client-library code or is it done on the server side?
- As it appears it is the client, the *client* would need expose this setting -- what the client lib/tool assumes this setting is. Is there any of the Oracle client libs/tools (sqlplus, OCI/OCCI, Pro*C, ...) that can be queried for what it thinks this setting is?

Comment: The view `v$session_connect_info` has a column `CLIENT_CHARSET` but it looks like most my data has the value of `Unknown` except for connections initiated on the database server, such as SQLPlus, and few others

Comment: See also See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/65863280/4178262 for more details on the `v$session_connect_info` view, and how hopeless it can be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am a little doubtful that this is exactly what you are looking for, but

```
host echo %nls_lang%;

ENGLISH_UNITED KINGDOM.WE8ISO8859P1
```

shows the client nls_lang environment variable on the client.

I don't think there will be a SQL query you can run to give the 'current' setting because AFAIK the server is not aware of what translation is done client-side, so any command to show the current setting will have to be native to the client - I used SQL Developer for the above command, but I assume it will work the same in SQL*Plus

--edit

[from AskTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1224836384599#6882973483777):

> only the client knows their character set as well -- it is not available "in the
> database"

[and](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1224836384599#20230102098470)

> the character set describes what is stored in database.
>
> the client makes their desired translated to character know [sic] to the database via the NLS_LANG
> settting.

If you were on 11.1+, [you might have some joy](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1224836384599#2683284000346049380) with v$session_connect_info, because:

> This information is pushed by OCI to the server ats login time.

But I discovered it would still depend on how you are connecting, eg from the JDBC Thin Driver you aren't using OCI and so the information isn't pushed

Comment: Well, no, it is *exactly not* what I was looking for :-) -- But you raise an (two) important point(s), and if it's true, I guess it would be an acceptable answer. I'll add the two points to the question.

Comment: Bah! (not to blame you) But Oracle really has it: "only the *client* knows their *character set* as well -- it is *not available "in the database"*" and "the client makes ... known to the database via the `NLS_LANG`" are really quite stating the opposite, no? :-)

Comment: Yes you are right though Tom<>Oracle. I think he is stumbling over his words - that whole thread is well worth skimming...

Comment: Accepted answer for the [1st link](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1224836384599#6882973483777) - because this question on Ask Tom (from 2002) actually asks the same thing "I would like to know if it is possible to check the client side NLS_LANG settings  in any of v$ or 
nls_ views once connected to the database."

Answer (score 0):

You can see [the following](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/functions150.htm):

- NLS_CALENDAR
- NLS_CURRENCY
- NLS_DATE_FORMAT
- NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE
- NLS_SORT
- NLS_TERRITORY

E.g:

```
SQL> select sys_context('USERENV', 'NLS_TERRITORY') from dual;

SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','NLS_TERRITORY')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
UNITED KINGDOM

1 row selected.
```

Comment: I guess mentioning sys_context here is useful. Otherwise this fails to address the problem of which *characterset*.

Comment: My point is that *these* are the only things that the server knows (or cares) about.